# What triggers "remote is newer" status for file during merge

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to have Mercurial output why it thinks a file is newer?

I have been trying to identify reasons for a non-contentual file change during a merge between branches of adjacent revisions. While I have am no closer to an acceptable answer after debugging the merge-process, it is definitively not whitespace-related. My best guess is something timestamp-related, but cannot prove this using known commands. Listed below is pseudo-code for the behavior I am experiencing:

```
// assumptions: repo. has two branches – development and default.
// related file has been committed to development at rev. x, merged into default
// at x+1 and default is merged back with development at x+2.
// rev. x has multiple files in the changeset, but only one appears with M-status when
// merging default back into development.

> hg branch
development
> hg commit file -m "Committing file..."
> hg update default
> hg merge development
> hg commit -m "Merge with development..."
> hg update development
> hg merge default --debug
 resolving manifests
  branchmerge: True, force: False, partial: False
  ancestor: ..., local: ..., remote: ...
  file: remote is newer -> g
getting src/Models/Query/IQuery.cs
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
> hg status
M file
> hg diff
>
```

I tried following Mercurial's [source code](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable/file/e2031c8ca4f8/mercurial/merge.py#l458) related to the "remote is newer" message, but it did not explain much for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have only two thoughts, neither of which are direct answers:

1. Try adding `--debug` to your merge command.
2. Double-check the timestamps of the files.  You say "cannot prove this using known commands", but there doesn't need to be a special Mercurial command to print the last-modified timestamp on a file.